# Error loading admin page after upgrading to django-1.11

Tags: python, django, django-1.11

So previously, I was using django-1.8 version & I am in the process of upgrading to django-1.11. When I load my /admin page, I get

```
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    admin/index.html
```

I have tried multiple options and dont know why django is not loading admin templates for django-1.11.

Few more details:
- I use django-jet for the admin interface
- My TEMPLATES in settings looks like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
          os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'custom_dir_1'),
          os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'custom_dir_2'),
          os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'custom_dir_3')
        ],
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
              'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
              'django.template.context_processors.request',
              'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
              'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
              'context_processors.base_context',
            ],
        }
    }
]
```

Let me know if I can provide any other information to debug better. Any guidance in this issue is super appreciated, Have been at this issue for 3rd consecutive day :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set [`APP_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#app-dirs) to `True`, i.e.:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'DIRS': [
        ...
```

Comment: I cannot thank you enough. that fixed my problem. i really appreciate your help !